# Actualizar imágenes para mi app android desde un servidor

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app de imágenes (tipo galería) en Android Studio y mi duda es cómo ir agregando más imágenes cada cierto tiempo sin tener que subir una actualización a la Play Store.

Por ejemplo, agregar más imágenes cada semana remotamente.

Answer (score 3):

Existen varias formas desde consultar las imágenes por medio de un Web Sevice cuya respuesta entregué un .json o .xml de las imágenes a desplegar en la galería.

Si deseas algo rápido te doy como ejemplo crear un .json o .xml accedido mediante http, el cual contenga los url de las imágenes, y el cual tu debes tener acceso a modificar:

```
<gallery name="imagenes galeria" version="1">
  <image url="http://www.mydomain.com/images/caine.jpg"/>
  <image url="http://www.mydomain.com/images/cal.jpg"/>
  <image url="http://www.mydomain.com/images/pui.jpg"/>
  <image url="http://www.mydomain.com/images/ursus.jpg"/>
  <image url="http://www.mydomain.com/images/cocos.jpg"/>
</gallery>
```

Cuando inicie tu aplicación, descargaría el archivo, parsearía y obtendría los url de las imágenes las cuales desplegaría en tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola a tod@s, esto es más bien una pregunta relacionada. Sería posible un bucle en la app de galería, para que mostrara las imágenes que encontrara en una carpeta almacenada en un servidor ? Me explico, en una carpeta imágenes, en "ipFija/carpetaCompartida" si tengo 10 imágenes, al abrir la app, realiza el bucle y mostraría las 10 imágenes. Si yo actualizo la carpeta, y almaceno otras 10 imágenes, al abrir la app, realizaría el bucle y al encontrar 20 imágenes, las mostraría en la app. No se si ésto sería posible ?

Answer (score 0):

Si te interesa algo mas sofisticado deberías armarte una API en una tecnología web (NodeJs con [express](http://expressjs.com/es/), por ejemplo) usando REST, donde hagas un POST para subir las imágenes y un get para obtenerlas. Luego en Android con una librería de web services (como Retrofit) le pegas a esa API y levantas las fotos. Es una solución mas complicada pero al menos así tenes una integración mejor. Si queres un ejemplo, podes mirar el código en github de mi [app de stackoverflow](https://github.com/maxwellnewage/stackoverflow-viewer).